# Explanation about a regular expression pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var rxDatePattern = new RegExp("^(?:\\d*\\.\\d{" + no + "})$");
```

This is the regular exp pattern im using to accept numeric values with 3 digits after decimal.The value is stored in the variable no....
This is working fine , but i kind of did not understand the pattern , can anybody help me the pattern..
Thanks

Comment: if you want to fiddle around with it: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` and `$` are anchors for the start and end of string, respectively. They make the regex match a complete string in this case instead of just a substring.

`\d` stands for a single digit, while `\d*` is, due to the `*` quantifier, a series of at least zero digits. Then follows a literal dot, matching, well, a dot (`.`) and a variable number of digits again, e.g. `\d{3}`.

The reason why the regex contains `\\d` instead of `\d` is that `\` is also the escape character for strings in JavaScript. So to include a literal backslash in a regex that is contained in a string you have to escape the backslash once, so the regex engine sees an actual backslash.

Finally all this is enclosed in a non-capturing group `(?:...)`, although I don't quite see why. It has no effect in this case and could be left out as well.

So for `no` = 2 this would match strings like

```
1.23
123.45
.00
```

but not strings like

```
.123
1.123
5.3
2
1.
```

Answer (score 0):

the first \d* is to say "many numbers or 0 before "."" 
then \d{3} (3 is the value of the var no) is to say "3 figures after the "."")

The starting "^" and the ending "$" is to say "exactly this pattern"

Comment: hey thank you for your reply ,,, i fail to understand why is \\d used instead of \d ,, is it the correct way ...

Comment: i don't know either, perhaps because of the "non-capturing group" that is set before the pattern (?:.....)

Comment: @freebird: To get a ``\`` in a string you'll have to escape it: ``\\``. So, ``\\d`` will make the string with the characters ``\d`` and that will be passed to the regexp constructor. ``\d`` will make a string with just the chracter ``d``.

Comment: Ok fine @pimvdb ,,, i understood that ,, but what about '\\.' could you please explain me that so that ill understand the whole pattern

Comment: ok. I did not know either. I thought that as d is not a special character \d became one, like in PCRE. I learnt something.

Comment: @freebird: ``\\.`` will make for ``\.`` which is a dot. ``\.`` would make for ``.`` which means "any character".

Comment: . is a special character means "everything" (apart from \n i think) if you want a "." to appear you must escape it with a "\".

Comment: thank you @artragis ,,, i realized today we can learn so much from ppl with same interests.thanks